# Cannot debug script tasks when running under the 64 bit version of the Integration Services runtime

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to debug Script task and it is giving me following error.

**"Cannot debug script tasks when running under the 64 bit version of the Integration Services runtime".**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the solution.
Need to change 'Run64bitRunTime' property to False.

1.Go to project menu in BIDS.

2.Go to properties.

3.In debugging category change the property 'Run64bitRunTime' to False.

Answer (score 0):

**please go to project menu in BIDS and go to properties, in debugging category, change the property 'Run64bitRunTime' to False.
after that, script debugging will start working.**

Interrupt execution and display a modal message by using the **MessageBox.Show** method in the System.Windows.Forms namespace. (Remove this code after you complete the debugging process.)
**strong text**

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/04/breakpoint-does-not-work-within-ssis.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136033.aspx